# Pivoting multiple date ranges in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my input data:

```
MEMBER_ID EVENT     AMT_SBSDY   PLAN_ID         EFF_DT          TERM_DT
314450    SBSDY     0           NULL            01-SEP-2017     31-DEC-2017
314450    SBSDY     0           NULL            01-JAN-2018     30-JUN-2018
314450    SBSDY     40          NULL            01-JUL-2018     31-DEC-9999
314450    PLN       0           032             01-JAN-2018     31-DEC-9999
```

and This is the expected output:

```
MEMBER_ID EVENT_SBSDY   EVENT_PLAN  AMT_SBSDY   PLAN_ID         EFF_DT          TERM_DT
314450    SBSDY         NULL        0           NULL            01-SEP-2017     31-DEC-2017
314450    SBSDY         PLN         0           032             01-JAN-2018     30-JUN-2018
314450    SBSDY         PLN         40          032             01-JUL-2018     31-DEC-9999
```

a member is an entity who has two different kinds of events (SBSDY - Subsidy amount and PLN - her plan ID).

In the first dataset the member has the first SBSDY event effective from 01-SEP-17 to 31-DEC-2017 and the subsidy amount is $0. The member has the second subsidy event effective from 01-JAN-2018 to 30-JUN-2018 (again $0) and the third subsidy event event of $40 effective from 01-JUL-2018 through Open ended (currently effective).

The member also has a PLN event effective from 01-JAN-2018 to Open ended date (currently effective). This event date range is overlapping with that of the second and third SUBSDY event so from 01-JAN-2018 to 01-JUN-2018 the member has subsidy amount of $0 and Plan ID 032 and from 01-JUL-2018 the member has subsidy amount of $40 and plan ID of 032.

I need to show this detail in the same row rather than in different rows (as in the source data set). In the output data set for the date range 01-SEP-2017 to 31-DEC-2017 subsidy amount is $0 and Plan ID and Event_Plan are NULL (first row). For the date range 01-JAN-2018 through 30-JUN-2018 Event Subsidy = SBSDY (the member has a Subsidy amount) and Event Plan = PLN (member has a Plan in that date range) and Plan ID is 032 and Subsidy = 0. The third row in the output data set shows the date range from 01-JUL-2018 through to date and in this row Subsidy amount is $40 and Plan ID is 032.

I think I need to do PIVOT but I am still unclear how to achieve this in this case.

My database is Oracle 12c Release 1.

Can you please help me.

Comment: Why that expected output? You have given some data and a result and nothing to indicate how you get from one to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear if the subsidy and plan dates always align as you've shown, but assuming they do you can get the most recent plan data with `keep dense_rank`:

```
select member_id,
  event,
  max(case when event = 'PLN' then event end)
    over (partition by member_id order by eff_dt) as event_plan,
  amt_sbsdy,
  max(case when event = 'PLN' then plan_id end)
    over (partition by member_id order by eff_dt) as plan_id,
  eff_dt,
  term_dt
from your_table
```

and then filter to only see the subsidy events:

```
-- CTE for your sample data
with your_table (member_id, event, amt_sbsdy, plan_id, eff_dt, term_dt) as (
            select 314450, 'SBSDY', 0, NULL, date '2017-09-01', date '2017-12-31' from dual
  union all select 314450, 'SBSDY', 0, NULL, date '2018-01-01', date '2018-06-30' from dual
  union all select 314450, 'SBSDY', 40, NULL, date '2018-01-07', date '2099-12-31' from dual
  union all select 314450, 'PLN', 0, '032', date '2018-01-01', date '2099-12-31' from dual
)
-- actual query
select member_id,
  event as event_sbsdy,
  event_plan,
  amt_sbsdy,
  plan_id,
  eff_dt,
  term_dt
from (
  select member_id,
    event,
    max(case when event = 'PLN' then event end)
      over (partition by member_id order by eff_dt) as event_plan,
    amt_sbsdy,
    max(case when event = 'PLN' then plan_id end)
      over (partition by member_id order by eff_dt) as plan_id,
    eff_dt,
    term_dt
  from your_table
)
where event = 'SBSDY'
order by member_id, eff_dt;

 MEMBER_ID EVENT_SBSDY EVENT_PLAN  AMT_SBSDY PLAN_ID EFF_DT     TERM_DT   
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ------- ---------- ----------
    314450 SBSDY                           0         2017-09-01 2017-12-31
    314450 SBSDY       PLN                 0 032     2018-01-01 2018-06-30
    314450 SBSDY       PLN                40 032     2018-01-07 2099-12-31
```